# Java FileNotFoundException though the file exists.

Tags: java, android

```
package com.test.methods;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.crumbin.main.R.color;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;



public class JsonParserActivity extends Activity {


    String strLine = null;
    String[] values = null;
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(com.main.R.layout.user_main);





              // Open the file that is the first 
              // command line parameter




            try {
                FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("/home/hic/jdata.txt");

              // Get the object of DataInputStream
              DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

              //Read File Line By Line

                while ((br.readLine()) != null)   {
                  // Print the content on the console
                      strLine = strLine + br.readLine();

                }
              this.parse(strLine);
              //Close the input stream

                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

              parse(strLine);


              ListView contactLV = (ListView) findViewById(com.crumbin.main.R.id.user_contact_list); 

              ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,com.main.R.layout.user_contact_list_item,com.main.R.id.contact_name,values);
                contactLV.setAdapter(adapter);




        }

    public void parse(String jsonLine) {
        JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonLine);
        JsonObject  jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();


        JsonArray jarray = jobject.getAsJsonArray("contact");

        jobject = jarray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();


        values[0]= jobject.get("user").toString();

    }


}
```

I've tried file.CanRead() and file.exist() and both return False. The file exists. Also, the file is not being read by any other process.

Comment: What exactly does the logcat say the error is

Comment: did you set up all permissions? and normally you would NOT want to save the file into the /home folder. save rather either into the /data/data/<app>/files or into /sdcard/ http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#AccessingExtFiles

Comment: Logcat says null point exception. I debugged it, and it is because the filestream is null.

Comment: @Hiccup: hum, in your code `fstream` cannot be `null`, `new` always returns an allocated object or throws an exception.

Comment: How's that the file exists and File.exists() is false? Are you sure?

Comment: I am pretty sure. The file exists. Else, I won't have got the absolute path to it.

Comment: In any case, don't open a file connection on the main thread. If the file is large enough you'll get an ANR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `canRead` doesn't work and the file actually exists, it means there is a permission problem.

Comment: agree with that .. other thing that may be the path is not correct .. but it looks strange to see such as path in Android world :)

Answer (score 2):

If canRead() and exists() return false even if the file actually exists then it means that the application doesn't have read rights on that file/folder...